What part number replaces TR0A2 on a 2012 Honda Civic?
I can't find this part number anywhere? What replaces it? It's my VSA anti-lock brake module. I broke it.
I have a 4 door, 2012, Honda Civic EX (automatic transmission).

What is the exact model of your vehicle? 2dr/4dr? EX/LX? Manual/Auto transmission? I see several different ABS part numbers which include "TR0-A2", but have more to it than that (ie: 57110-TR0-A25), but not TR0A2 by itself. What I'm looking at shows different part numbers based off the setup of the car, so need full description to get you where you want to be.

@Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 have a 2012 HONDA CIVIC EX. I've updated the question with that.

Yes, but is it a 4dr or 2dr? Is it automatic or standard shift. All these different vehicle types have different ABS modules.

@Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 that's enough reason for me never to buy a Honda again. But I updated the question. I can't imagine a 4dr or 2dr making a difference in the ABS module. Lol.

I believe the part number you're looking for is Honda PN: 57110-TR0-A25. This is the part for a 2012 Honda Civic 4-door EX Automatic.
If you are wondering why there seems to be a ton of different part numbers for all the different models, I'd venture to assume they are actually physically all the same, yet programmed differently to account for things like wheel speed, weight distribution, braking bias, and probably a ton of other things I can't imagine.

Deadlink, otherwise exceptional answer.

@EvanCarroll - I updated it with a generic Google search. TY for pointing it out to me. Much appreciated :o)

Even here though it says the part suggested is discontinued https://www.hondapartsnow.com/genuine/honda~modulator~assy~vsa~57110-tr0-a25.html
